# How to transfer json string to another page using jquery's ajax method?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a JSON string (stringified array of objects in javascript) which i intend to post to another page and then retrieve it from the `$_POST` variable.  I used `json      =JSON.stringify(array)`.

The result gave me the following string

```
json = [{"keycodec":68,"eventc":"keydown","timec":1392849542994}
        {"keycodec":65,"eventc":"keydown","timec":1392849543063},
        {"keycodec":87,"eventc":"keydown","timec":1392849543084}]
```

Now I use

```
$( "#other").click(function() {
  $.ajax({

    url: 'some.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { kite : json}

});
```

On the page some.php I use

```
$kite=json_decode($_POST['kite'],true);

print_r($kite)
```

But nothing shows up. I have read many links on this topic and tried adding ContentType,dataType,processData parameters to the `$.ajax()` function but nothing helped.

Comment: *"But nothing shows up"* You don't seem to be doing anything with the response of the Ajax call.

Comment: Have you used a tool such as FireBug or the Chrome dev tools to see the response of your ajax request? You should see the results of your print_r() statement in the "Response" of the request. As @Felix King mentions, you aren't handling the success response of the ajax call.

Comment: `dataType: 'json'` must be added to ajax call

Comment: also make it `data: json` ...instead of wrapping in `{}`

Comment: @Vikram: No, then the PHP wouldn't work. The data is still sent as form data, so you have to associate it with a key ("kite" is the key here). And since the PHP code doesn't return JSON, `dataType: 'json'` is incorrect.

Comment: @FelixKling thats correct!

Comment: You can add something like: `success: function(r) { alert(r) }` to see have the output of the php page alert'd.

Comment: I get an Internal Server error with Initiator jquery.js:8724 on Devtools.Please help and when i say Nothing shows up i meant nothing shows up on the some.php page

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
$( "#other").click(function() {

  var json = [{"keycodec":68,"eventc":"keydown","timec":1392849542994}
        ,{"keycodec":65,"eventc":"keydown","timec":1392849543063},
        {"keycodec":87,"eventc":"keydown","timec":1392849543084}];

  $.ajax({

    url: 'test.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: "kite=" + JSON.stringify({ kite : json }),

    success: function(msg){
        alert(msg);
    },
    failure: function(errMsg) {
        alert(errMsg);
    }
  });

});
```

And on your php code:

```
<?php

$obj=json_decode($_POST['kite']);

print_r($obj->{'kite'});
?>
```

Not in an elegant way on passing the json..
 but this way you can still capture "kite" as post variable and decode your desired json string.